# Which are the better choices of "post" and "position" and "place" and "location" respectively?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

At the end of an agreement, where the parties sign, one may want to include the position/post of the signees and the place where the document was signed, like so:

Name_____________

Position/Post_____________

Place/Location_____________

Date_____________

Now I'm wondering which are the better words among the alternatives – *post* or *position*? *Place* or *location*? Or should I use something else entirely?

Comment: You need to specify 'location where document signed', otherwise it looks as though you are asking for the place where the person works.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh – right, thanks! I take it "location" is better than "place" then? And what if I put it on the same line as "Date"? So: "Date and location____________" Would that work? And which is better of "post" and "position"?

Comment: I used _location_ because it occurred to me that 'place where document signed' might be answered with 'at the bottom'! I don't think I've ever seen a document that asked for that information, though. Off the top of my head, I think _position_ would be more usual.

Comment: @KateBunting :))  Thanks. And no, nor have I (seen any agreements etc including this info, I mean) – hence my need to ask which word to use... Thing is, where I'm from it would never ever occur to anyone NOT to include location... Anyway, despite it being generally odd, do you think it would work to use "location" only (rather than "location where document signed") if I put it together with the date? So: "Date and location____________"?

Comment: Use "job title" rather than the ambiguous "position" or "post". Then I would go: Name, Job title, Date, Location

Comment: @gotube Thank you! Much better!